# Azure Log Analytics :: List all databases with their size in GB

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, azure-log-analytics, kusto-explorer, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I was following [this guide](https://kustoqueries.com/Databases/Azure-SQL/) and I found a good piece of code that could help me find a list of SQL Databases along with their:

- Used space
- Remaining space
- Allocated space
- Max storage

The code is this:

```
AzureMetrics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.SQL" and Resource != "MASTER"
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
| where MetricName == "storage"
| extend AverageMB = Average / 1000000
| summarize MaxMB = max(AverageMB) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h), Resource
| project TimeGenerated, Resource, MaxMB
```

Unfortunately when I run it it shows multiple entries for the same database.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and below rea my expected results:

**`Note:`**

When ever you use **`summarize() on time,`** you will always get multiple entries, because it is grouping results on time also which is not recommended as you will get duplicate or multiple entries like below:

Below is example KQL query :

```
AzureMetrics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.SQL" and Resource != "MASTER"
| extend AverageMB = Average / 1000000
| summarize MaxMB = max(AverageMB) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h), Resource
| project TimeGenerated, Resource, MaxMB
```

[image]

here, there are multiple entries. To remove these use below query(integrate below query into yours query):

```
AzureMetrics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.SQL" and Resource != "MASTER"
| project Resource,TimeGenerated,Average
| extend AverageMB = Average / 1000000
| summarize MaxMB = max(AverageMB) by  Resource
```

[image]

So, I would suggest not to use summarize() on time as it does grouping on time. You will get results grouped on a particular time and size.